# How do I get the hotel codes for the given city from Amadeus hotel API?

Tags: python, api, google-colaboratory, amadeus

I am not fluent in Python and do not understand clearly Amadeus API Python codes online. It is a work in progress.
I want to find the code for the specific hotel and find its information with specific check-in and check-out dates.
So, how do I get the hotel codes for the given city?
I am using Google Colab.

```
!pip install amadeus
from amadeus import ResponseError, Client

amadeus = Client(
    client_id='My ID',
    client_secret='My secret'
)

try:
    # Get list of Hotels by city code
    hotels_by_city = amadeus.shopping.hotel_offers_search.get(
        hotelIds='RTPAR001', adults='2')
except ResponseError as error:
    raise error
print(hotels_by_city)
```

I used this but it's not working.
Please help.
Thanks.

I tried this code to find the hotel codes but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hotels APIs flow in Amadeus Self-Service API is recently updated with a new version so you may have an outdated code example.

Hotel Booking engine flow is available in detail here :
https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/build-hotel-booking-engine-amadeus-api

- First endpoint to get the hotel id is Hotel List API
- 2nd endpoint to search price(offer id) based on Hotel Is is Hotel Search API
- the last endpoint to book the offer is Hotel Booking API

Each code examples are available in the documentation :
https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/examples/code-example/#hotel-list